# Angular 13 build not creating polyfills-es5.js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After trying to migrate form Angular 9 to 13, ng build --configuration production is not creating the ***polyfills-es5.js*** file which I need for **IE 11**. Is there any way to support IE 11 in Angular 13..?

I tried below things

**Updated tsconfig.json file to target to es5**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

**Updated polyfills.ts files**

```
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
import 'core-js';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
```

I also read somewhere to update the browserslist file, but I am not able to find browserslist file in my project folder.

Comment: I think in angular version 13 and onwards they drop support for IE 11

Comment: Is there any way to add polyfills to support IE11...?

Comment: microsoft will drop support for IE11 after june 2022

Comment: On the official site of Angular, IE isn't listet as well :/ https://angular.io/guide/browser-support. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-ie-11

Comment: I think they are using browserlist to determine if the es5 build required

Comment: form browserlistsrc.json, I removed the NOT from NOT IE11, but still its not generating polyfills-es5 file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192247/why-does-angular-build-create-files-with-es5-and-es2015-but-not-es6-or-no

Comment: you have to run NGCC post install then use npm run build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all about transpiling to the correct module def and pulling in the correct polyfills (shims) for ie11. It's a pain now :(

https://www.bitovi.com/blog/ie-11-and-angular-overview.html